# ruby on rails and bootstrap , make field_with_errors display horizontal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, field-with-errors

in `custom.css.scss` file

```
.field_with_errors {
    @extend .control-group;
    @extend .error;

}
```

and the html.erb

```
<%= form_for @timecard , url:{action: "savecard"},html:{class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :"Date"%>
    <%= f.date_select :starttime ,{use_month_numbers: true }, class: "input-small" %>
    <%= f.label :"Hours"%>
    <%= f.number_field :hours, class: "input-small" %>
    <%= f.label :"Project"%>
    <% projects = Project.all.map { |project| [project.name, project.charge_number]  } %>
    <%= f.select :charge_number, options_for_select(projects) ,{},class: "input-small" , style:"width:150px"%>
    <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn" %>
    <%= f.submit "Delete", class: "btn" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-danger",confirm:"You can't edit it agin if you've submitted it" %>
<% end %>
```

In normal status ,it looks nice

[image]
but if something wrong happened,it looks like this
[image]

and the html code it generated

```
<label for="time_card_Hours">Hours</label>
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input class="input-small" id="time_card_hours" name="time_card[hours]" type="number" /></div>
    <label for="time_card_Project">Project</label>
```

Comment: Could you also show `.control-group .error` css classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using form-inline, and div displays as a block default. try

```
.field_with_errors {
    @extend .control-group;
    @extend .error;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that with Bootstrap 3 [names have changed](http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide#cheat-cheat)

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: And with Bootstrap 4 they changed again: has-error -> is-invalid.  

[Credit to this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70589481/did-the-validation-state-classes-has-error-etc-got-removed-from-bootstrap-5)

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the following:

```
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
}

.form-inline .field_with_errors {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This extends the `.has-error` Bootstrap class for all forms, and if the form used is an inline form (.`form-inline`), it displays `.field_with_errors` as `inline-block`.

Comment: looks like a better solution