# Instead of show a notice error, show the error in the input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an rails app with Twitter Bootstrap that when validates an object (like name, and the name is blank) I get an error, but in a flash/notice, like the image bellow:[image: imagem]

Okay, but, instead of that, i wish that the error shows in the inputs, and the classes of the inputs would be .has-error (or something like that). I take a look into the field_error_proc and tried to change it, but unsuccessfull.

Comment: you can add `<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>` after `<%= yield %>` in views/layout/application.html.erb. It will show the details of the parameters passed by the form to the controller

Comment: Im forcing to show this error. What i really want is to show the error in the input, and not in a notice/popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've done this before (you can see at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk - click "register")

--

**Errors**

The way we did it was to [use the following](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors):

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

   <%= f.text_field :your_param %>
   <%= @user.errors[:your_param].first if @user.errors[:your_param].present? %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Something else you need to consider is that Rails automatically appends the [`field_with_errors`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307376/ruby-on-rails-and-bootstrap-make-field-with-errors-display-horizontal) class to any input with an error. If you wanted to style the error-laden input, you'll be able to use the styling suggestions in the attached answer

Comment: Ok. That works for me, but, in my case, the `field_with_erros` class is not appended to the input with an error. I dont know if this is specificity of a gem or something. I know that I can do this using jQuery.. but.. you know, it would be like an line of js to each control/view.

Answer (score 0):

I set the field_error_proc as blow in my project, it works fine

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  case instance
  when ::ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Label
    html_tag
  else
    error_message = instance.error_message.is_a?(Array) ?
      instance.error_message.join(', ') :
      instance.error_message

    %Q(<div class="has-error">#{html_tag}<div class='help-block'>#{error_message}</div></div>).html_safe
  end
end
```